# Content Delivery Network for html files

Tags: node.js

I would like to know how I could setup a CDN in Nodejs but for html files. Basically I would like my website to call to another server with a html filename then the cdn returns the file back to the website then I render it to the page. I really don't know where to start and any boosters would greatly help!

Comment: That's not a CDN, that's a document store like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/getting-started/) or [Riak](http://basho.com/products/).

Comment: If you actually *need* a CDN, you will know it because your main server is being swamped by requests for (largely) static files. On WebFaction.com (I'm not a shill, just a happy customer) you can easily set it up so that the frontend nginx server handles all static requests, and the other server (Apache) handles stuff that needs computation. I use this for all of my Django sites I host there.

Comment: Okay, terrific thank you!